# ionic cannot reach by local IP

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to ionic / macos,
when i start ionic serve ,
i can view it on macos web browser (http://localhost:8100)
however, i cannot open it by remote device at the same LAN by IP address  (http://192.168.1.100:8100)

I did the following checking
macos side
network utility , port scan 8100 success

remote device (ipad)
ping 192.168.1.100 ok
port scan 192.168.1.100 not success

Then, i read the forum and try 
ionic serve --address 192.168.1.100

This time, macos (http://192.168.1.100:8100) success

but remote device (not success)

Pls. help if any setting on macos can be done. thanks

Comment: You checked the firewall?

Comment: is the remote device connected to the same network??